# How to get the JSFiddle to a working HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following code:

```js
/**Quagga initialiser starts here*/

$(function() {
  var value;
  var App = {
    init: function() {
      Quagga.init(this.state, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        App.attachListeners();
        Quagga.start();
      });
    },
    initCameraSelection: function() {
      var streamLabel = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveStreamLabel();

      return Quagga.CameraAccess.enumerateVideoDevices()
        .then(function(devices) {
          function pruneText(text) {
            return text.length > 30 ? text.substr(0, 30) : text;
          }
          var $deviceSelection = document.getElementById("deviceSelection");
          while ($deviceSelection.firstChild) {
            $deviceSelection.removeChild($deviceSelection.firstChild);
          }
          devices.forEach(function(device) {
            var $option = document.createElement("option");
            $option.value = device.deviceId || device.id;
            $option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pruneText(device.label || device.deviceId || device.id)));
            $option.selected = streamLabel === device.label;
            $deviceSelection.appendChild($option);
          });
        });
    },
    querySelectedReaders: function() {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.readers input[type=checkbox]'))
        .filter(function(element) {
          return !!element.checked;
        })
        .map(function(element) {
          return element.getAttribute("name");
        });
    },
    attachListeners: function() {
      var self = this;

      self.initCameraSelection();
      $(".controls").on("click", "button.stop", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Quagga.stop();
      });

      $(".controls .reader-config-group").on("change", "input, select", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(e.target);
        // value = $target.attr("type") === "checkbox" ? $target.prop("checked") : $target.val(),
        value = $target.attr("type") === "checkbox" ? this.querySelectedReaders() : $target.val();
        var name = $target.attr("name"),
          state = self._convertNameToState(name);

        console.log("Value of " + state + " changed to " + value);
        self.setState(state, value);
      });
    },
    _accessByPath: function(obj, path, val) {
      var parts = path.split('.'),
        depth = parts.length,
        setter = (typeof val !== "undefined") ? true : false;

      return parts.reduce(function(o, key, i) {
        if (setter && (i + 1) === depth) {
          if (typeof o[key] === "object" && typeof val === "object") {
            Object.assign(o[key], val);
          } else {
            o[key] = val;
          }
        }
        return key in o ? o[key] : {};
      }, obj);
    },
    _convertNameToState: function(name) {
      return name.replace("_", ".").split("-").reduce(function(result, value) {
        return result + value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
      });
    },
    detachListeners: function() {
      $(".controls").off("click", "button.stop");
      $(".controls .reader-config-group").off("change", "input, select");
    },
    setState: function(path, value) {
      var self = this;

      if (typeof self._accessByPath(self.inputMapper, path) === "function") {
        value = self._accessByPath(self.inputMapper, path)(value);
      }

      self._accessByPath(self.state, path, value);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(self.state));
      App.detachListeners();
      Quagga.stop();
      App.init();
    },
    inputMapper: {
      inputStream: {
        constraints: function(value) {
          if (/^(\d+)x(\d+)$/.test(value)) {
            var values = value.split('x');
            return {
              width: {
                min: parseInt(values[0])
              },
              height: {
                min: parseInt(values[1])
              }
            };
          }
          return {
            deviceId: value
          };
        }
      },
      numOfWorkers: function(value) {
        return parseInt(value);
      },
      decoder: {
        readers: function(value) {
          if (value === 'ean_extended') {
            return [{
              format: "ean_reader",
              config: {
                supplements: [
                  'ean_5_reader', 'ean_2_reader'
                ]
              }
            }];
          }
          console.log("value before format :" + value);
          return [{
            format: value + "_reader",
            config: {}
          }];
        }
      }
    },
    state: {
      inputStream: {
        type: "LiveStream",
        constraints: {
          width: {
            min: 640
          },
          height: {
            min: 480
          },
          aspectRatio: {
            min: 1,
            max: 100
          },
          facingMode: "environment" // or user
        }
      },
      locator: {
        patchSize: "large",
        halfSample: true
      },
      numOfWorkers: 4,
      decoder: {
        readers: ["code_39_reader", "code_128_reader"]
      },
      locate: true,
      multiple: true
    },
    lastResult: null
  };

  //value =  App.querySelectedReaders() ;
  App.init();

  Quagga.onProcessed(function(result) {
    var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
      drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

    if (result) {
      if (result.boxes) {
        drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
        result.boxes.filter(function(box) {
          return box !== result.box;
        }).forEach(function(box) {
          Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, {
            x: 0,
            y: 1
          }, drawingCtx, {
            color: "green",
            lineWidth: 2
          });
        });
      }

      if (result.box) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, {
          x: 0,
          y: 1
        }, drawingCtx, {
          color: "#00F",
          lineWidth: 2
        });
      }

      if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, {
          x: 'x',
          y: 'y'
        }, drawingCtx, {
          color: 'red',
          lineWidth: 3
        });
      }
    }
  });

  Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
    var code = result.codeResult.code;

    if (App.lastResult !== code) {
      App.lastResult = code;
      var $node = null,
        canvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.image;

      $node = $('<li><h4 class="code"></h4></li></br>');
      $node.find("img").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL());
      $node.find("h4.code").html(code);
      $("#result_strip ul.thumbnails").prepend($node);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.collapsable-source pre {
  font-size: small;
}

.input-field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 260px;
}

.input-field label {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.input-field input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 20px;
}

.input-field button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
}

.icon-barcode {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.overlay {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.overlay__content {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.overlay__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: -1rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  z-index: 100;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.overlay__content video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay__content canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#interactive.viewport {
  position: relative;
}

#interactive.viewport>canvas,
#interactive.viewport>video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

canvas.drawing,
canvas.drawingBuffer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}


/* line 16, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls fieldset {
  border: none;
}


/* line 19, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls .input-group {
  float: left;
}


/* line 21, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls .input-group input,
.controls .input-group button {
  display: block;
}


/* line 25, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls .reader-config-group {
  float: right;
}


/* line 28, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls .reader-config-group label {
  display: block;
}


/* line 30, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls .reader-config-group label span {
  width: 11rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}


/* line 37, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

.controls:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* line 22, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/* line 28, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* line 37, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 160px;
}


/* line 41, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
}


/* line 46, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail img {
  max-width: 140px;
}


/* line 49, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail .caption {
  white-space: normal;
}


/* line 51, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail .caption h4 {
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* line 61, ../sass/_viewport.scss */

#result_strip ul.thumbnails:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 603px) {
  /* line 2, ../sass/phone/_core.scss */
  #container {
    margin: 10px auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 603px) {
  /* line 5, ../sass/phone/_viewport.scss */
  #interactive.viewport {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* line 20, ../sass/phone/_viewport.scss */
  #result_strip {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  #result_strip ul.thumbnails {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* line 24, ../sass/phone/_viewport.scss */
  #result_strip ul.thumbnails>li {
    width: 150px;
  }
  /* line 27, ../sass/phone/_viewport.scss */
  #result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail .imgWrapper {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* line 31, ../sass/phone/_viewport.scss */
  #result_strip ul.thumbnails>li .thumbnail .imgWrapper img {
    margin-top: -25px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 180px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quagga/0.11.6/quagga.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<section id="container" class="container">
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/cuyzds2d/">test link</a>
  <h3>The user's camera</h3>
  <p>If your platform supports the <strong>getUserMedia</strong> API call, you can try the real-time locating and decoding features. Simply allow the page to access your web-cam and point it to a barcode.</p>
  <p>The various options available allow you to adjust the decoding process to your needs (Type of barcode, resolution, ...)</p>
  <div class="controls">
    <fieldset class="input-group">
      <button class="stop">Stop</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="reader-config-group" hidden>
      <label>
        <span>Barcode-Type</span>
        <select name="decoder_readers">
        <option value="code_39_reader" selected="selected" hidden>Code 128</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Resolution (long side)</span>
        <select name="input-stream_constraints">
        <option selected="selected" value="640x480" hidden>640px</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Patch-Size</span>
        <select name="locator_patch-size">
        <option selected="selected" value="medium" hidden>medium</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Half-Sample</span>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="locator_half-sample" hidden />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Workers</span>
        <select name="numOfWorkers">
        <option selected="selected" value="1" hidden>4</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Camera</span>
        <select name="input-stream_constraints" id="deviceSelection">
        </select>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="result_strip">
    <ul class="thumbnails"></ul>
  </div>
  <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
</section>
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArcherMark/9Lubqrr4/70/**

And now I am looking to implement it into my website. But for some reason it won't work: [**jsfiddle.net/ArcherMark/677s8nv4/9/**](http://jsfiddle.net/ArcherMark/677s8nv4/9/)

Also this scanner is only working on non-iOS devices, is there something in the line of code which it is not running on iOS?

Hope that someone might know what's going on.

This next link relates to the image following. It is the code I have on my localhost: [**jsfiddle.net/ArcherMark/wLypzsss/**](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcherMark/wLypzsss/)

[image]

Comment: Have you include the plug-in's required for you to run that source code?

Comment: Please elaborate in detail what "it wont work" means. What isn't working exactly? What errors do you get? Also, what does "this scanner is only working on non IOS devices" mean? What scanner?

Comment: @NewToJS I have done script tags to include the plug-ins. was that wrong?

Comment: @j08691 it wont access the camera. have u looked at the working code and what it does? it is a barcode scanner

Comment: @rene sorry I don't understand what u mean as I don't have much knowledge about Javascript

Comment: @Mark I would suggest you open the browser console and check for errors. I know accessing camera/mic devices via google chrome can cause problems if it isn't using **HTTPS** but if that is the problem then it will be clearly stated in the browser console so please check there for any errors and return with further information. If you do see any errors please include them into your question as this can help lead you to a solution.

Comment: I just had a look when running it on my localhost. I got an error  SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined @NewToJS

Comment: @Mark check whether you have imported jquery or not ? if not then import it before any other script.

Comment: @Mark Are you sure you have included the `jQuery` library before trying to use the `jQuery` syntax within your `javascript`?

Comment: You must be missing the required libraries since this works fine for me [**Full Source Code - PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/0seNmNei)

Comment: @NewToJS hi there, thankyou for providing me with you're PasteBin. I have just one question which browser did u test it on? as I seem to only get it working on Firefox where I need to allow the camera access everytime but with chrome I only would need to do it one for the device... also it wont run on my pc with the cammer which it did on the jsfiddle. do you have any idea on what could cause that?